# How do I analyze the data using fuzzy logic?

Tags: function, member, fuzzy

I have a likert scale data sheet (perception based) with a total of 28 questions from 10 departments. The likert scale is as follows: 2.5, 5, 7.5 , 10.

How do I carry out fuzzy analysis on the data?

I am still confused so have read a few papers.

Expecting to apply fuzzy logic on the data sheet